# Activating a button if another button is activated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton

So I want to activate a button only if other multiple buttons are activated, in this case those multiple buttons are Button1, so when it is activated, it should also active button readyToRun

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI; // Required when Using UI elements.

public class GratzScript : MonoBehaviour
{        
    public Button Button1;
    public Button readyToRun;

    public void Update()
    {            
        if (Button1.enabled == true)
        {
            readyToRun.enabled = true;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what doesn't work about what you are doing?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I mean this script compiles, but it does not work when I run it.

Comment: I guess I should have a logical mistake maybe

Comment: What do you mean by button enable? Checking if a button is clicked ?or checking if the button is active in the scene?

Comment: Checking if button is Active in the scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Gameobject.activeInHierarchy

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html

```
 GameObject.activeSelf;         //Returns if the object is active or not
 GameObject.activeInHierarchy;  //Return if the object is active in the scene
```

You should set gameobjects active/inactive in  scene using setActive(true/false)

```
if(Button1.activeInHierarchy==true)
{
readyToRun.setActive(true);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand how can I use those functions Button1.activeSelf does not work, nor Button1.activeInHierarchy

Comment: Please give me a bit more detailed answer, as I am new to Unity and c#

Comment: if(Button1.activeInHierarchy == true) {   }

or

 if (Button1.activeInHierarchy) {    }   use this in your code instead of button1.enabled